# `from typing import ...` in all Python files canonical Python code?

Tags: python

The PyCharm issues [24494](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-24494) and [24112](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-24112) suggest that I always should do `from typing import ...` (whatever I use, or maybe even just `*`) in my Python files when I want to use type hinting. Otherwise PyCharm would complain with warnings such as `unresolved reference Union` or `unresolved reference Dict`.

Is that canonical Python code to have `from typing import ...` in all my Python files? I have never seen that (looking at popular big projects with Python code, e.g. [TensorFlow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/data_flow_ops.py), or most from [GitHub trending Python repositories](https://github.com/trending/python?since=monthly), or [CPython itself](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/os.py)).

---

I am not sure if this is a subjective question but there are many guidelines by Python PEPs which suggest how to write canonical Python code, so an objective answer could state that either "yes, this PEP says that it is canonical Python code" or "no, there is no such PEP, and not much code which does that". I define *canonical Python code* as either recommended by a PEP or found in most modern Python code.

Comment: How do you mean "never seen that"? :)

Comment: @errata: I added some links. Looking at other peoples Python code.

Comment: I voted to close this question as "primarily opionion-based" because there's no "absolute" technical answer, but as far as I'm concerned aftrer reading the linked issues it's __totally__ unpythonic - on two points actually : first, because importing symbols that are only used in comments targeted at the IDE is a (double) WTF, then because star imports (`from xxx import *`) is a bad practice that leads to maintenance nightmares. 

And that's indeed something I've never seen this in any published Python code so far...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: So, actually, isn't your comment a good objective answer to the question? Such things as how much published Python code there is using this can be measured, so it's not really only an opinion.

Comment: [Randomly picked popular Python library source code](https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/master/requests/adapters.py) and also [PEP8 about imports](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports).

Comment: I doubt you'll find anything _canonical_ about type annotations, they're still very young. I like namespaces and honestly would prefer even `import typing as T` and using `T.Dict` instead of wildcard import. This gives you some form of brevity as well as does not pollute all of your namespaces. Still, it likely should be closed, I don't think you'll get other answers that opinion-based.

Comment: @Albert as Lukasz mentions type hints annotations are a rather recent addition to the language so obviously one can't expect to find much code base using it so far. Whether they will get widely adopted or not is still so far an open question. Actually whether having type hints at all was a good idea is still bordering on religion war...

Comment: @errata: I don't see any `from typing import ...` in your linked source code nor in the PEP.

Comment: @Albert I think that was his point :) .

Comment: What exactly is "canonical Python code" supposed to mean?

Comment: @Albert Hm, sorry, I misunderstood your original question. I though it is about importing packages, not about type hinting :/ My bad and apologise ;)

Comment: @jwodder: I added a definition.